# How many tailing zeros in a result of (long) multiplication

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation, multiplication

I want to find out a number of tailing zeros in a result of multiplication there are.

My multiplication always gets out of `long` range and I found no other way other than use a bigint, but I want to avoid that for efficiency.  Is there a faster way to find the trailing zero count of the product, without actually computing it in a BigInteger?

Comment: You say you can't use `BigInteger`. Why can't you use it? It seems like the most reasonable way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Would not be efficent for my usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to multiply, multiplication (of the kind where two k-bit integers go in, and a 2k-bit integer comes out) *usually* has the property:

```
tzcnt(x * y) = tzcnt(x) + tzcnt(y)
```

This breaks down when `x` or `y` are zero, in that case the answer would be 2k regardless of how many trailing zeroes the other operand had.

So that leads to a simple algorithm:

1. if either input is zero, return 2k
2. otherwise, return `tzcnt(x) + tzcnt(y)`

This property comes from the way the partial products work: the lowest partial product (corresponding to the rightmost set bit in `x`) shifts `y` left by however many trailing zeroes `x` had, so this partial product has `tzcnt(x) + tzcnt(y)` trailing zeroes. Adding the other partial products never destroys this property since they are added at higher bit positions.